# How is the UML format for this relational operator?

Tags: c++

How is the UML format for this relational operator?
inline bool operator == (Jd const& lhs, Jd const& rhs) { return lhs.jd() == rhs.jd(); }

Answer (score 0):

```
inline operator== (lhs : Jd const&,  rhs : Jd const&) : bool
```

Here you go, don't forget the + / - / # sign depending of it being public / private / protected